# trying to install valgrind but stuck at make valgrind, how?

Tags: c, makefile, valgrind, gnu-make

This might be a silly question, actually I have just started with it. 
I am following a tutorial to [LCTHW](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html)

and I am trying to install valgrind, the author specifies steps:

## 1) Download it (use wget if you don't have curl)

curl -O http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

## use md5sum to make sure it matches the one on the site

md5sum valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

## 2) Unpack it.

tar -xjvf valgrind-3.6.1.tar.bz2

## cd into the newly created directory

cd valgrind-3.6.1

## 3) configure it

./configure

## 4) make it

make

## 5) install it (need root)

sudo make install

I am stuck at step 4, what to make here? What should the command look like? I have made c programs before but which specific file in here do I need to specify?

This is what I get when I run make:

```
Blackbeard@PC-DEV-A179:~/valgrind-3.6.1$ make
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

#### Edit:

As pinted out by user43250937, `./configure` is not working properly, I get the following:

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for ar... /usr/bin/ar
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for gdb... /usr/bin/gdb
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking for diff -u... yes
checking for a supported version of gcc... ok (4.8.2)
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for a supported CPU... ok (x86_64)
checking for a 64-bit only build... no
checking for a 32-bit only build... no
checking for a supported OS... ok (linux-gnu)
checking for the kernel version... unsupported (3.13.0-49-generic)
configure: error: Valgrind works on kernels 2.4, 2.6
```

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: You should simply try `sudo aptitude install valgrind` since Ubuntu packages it.

Comment: I wanted to do it the Hard way!

Comment: Then run `sudo aptitude build-dep valgrind` first

Comment: Now as you have made me curious, I would need to research on that too, thanks mate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 3 (configure), likely didn't complete correctly due to missing dependecies/libraries, check the output of that command.

Edit: You need a newer version of Valgrind that supports kernel 3.x, now they are at `valgrind-3.10.1`, that will work.

Comment: Yes mate, you are right. I missed that. I have updated my question.

Comment: Hi User, you need a newer version of Valgrind, download 3.10.1.

Comment: Thanks mate, let me try that :)

Comment: Or install it with apt-get :)

Answer (score 1):

From your output:

```
configure: error: Valgrind works on kernels 2.4, 2.6
```

Did you download a ridiculously old copy of valgrind?  Also, on Ubuntu, you can just

```
sudo apt-get install valgrind
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try with 3.10.1 once more, if it does not work. I will do as you suggest!

Comment: Just install it with the package manager that way you don't have to worry about upgrading it or removing it and just let Ubuntu take care of it.  It'll also be a lot faster than compiling.